# Error: Model Item passed into dictionary missmatch

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, ienumerable

Im tring to make a custom viewmodel class which takes 2 model list or enumerable. when I try to show in a view class it gives me following error.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ""Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel]""

I have tried making seperate views and used simple models to project in a view. it works fine but when i try to get viewmodel it does not works as i expect.

```
public class StockController : Controller
```

{

```
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public StockController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    // GET: Stock
    public ActionResult StockIndex()
    {
        var batteries = _context.Batteries.ToList();
        var rims = _context.Rims.ToList();
        var viewmodel = new StockViewModel
        {
            Batteries = batteries,
            Rims = rims
        };

        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

}

```
public class StockViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Battery> Batteries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rim> Rims { get; set; }
}

        @model IEnumerable<Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "StockIndex";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Stock Management</h2>

@if (!Model.Any())
{
<p>We don't have any Batteries yet.</p>
<label class="btn-group">@Html.ActionLink("Add New", "New", "Battery") 
 </label>
 }
 else
 {
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>battery ID</th>
            <th>battery Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var bt in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> tying to show batteries here</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rim ID</th>
            <th>Rim Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var rm in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> tying to show Rims here</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

}

I am trying to store data in controller method and send viewmodel to just show 2 tables with Id and name from database table Batteries and Rims

on the other hand, I am getting an exception 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the Model, rather than over individual enumerators; Batteries and Rims in your ViewModel.

So change the line:

```
@foreach (var bt in Model)
```

To:

```
@foreach (var bt in Model.Batteries)
```

And the same for you rims:

```
@foreach (var rm in Model)
```

To:

```
@foreach (var rm in Model.Rims)
```

Also change:

```
@model IEnumerable<Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel>
```

to:

```
@model Prototype01.ViewModels.StockViewModel
```

Comment: Model.Batteries not available

Comment: my error is somewhere in between passing the viewmodel and receiving it in view.

Comment: I tried debuging, when return view(viewModel) is called; it shows count in viewmodel object.

Comment: You have declared your ViewModel as Enumerable, i have updated my answer

Comment: I have tried that as well, removing IEnumerable but then it says  Model.Any() not found.

Comment: Correct, since your ViewModel is not enumerable. The `@if (!Model.Any())` should be changed to `@if (!Model.Batteries.Any())`